# Is it possible to redirect to another page and fill a field in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a website in react. There is a 'Request Access' button in the login page. If user clicks on that button,  I want to redirect to an access granting website. There is a search field in the access granting website. I want to autofill it with the text 'ACCESS-REQUIRED-FOR-OPs-APP'. I guessing this isn't possible. But is there any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, redirect with state:

```
<Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/results',
    state: { autofill: 'ACCESS-REQUIRED-FOR-OPs-APP' }
}}/>
```

and then in your access granting component:

```
<input type='text' value={this.props.location.state.autofill} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im sorry I should've been more clearer. I can't view or edit the code of the access website.

Comment: If you can't modify the target html file, then no, it's impossible :)